# Want to demonstrate my object property instead of my object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have DropDownList that read fils from my database and show this files in my DropDownList.

The current solution is show on my DropDownListItem System.Web.Mvc.SelectList instead of my Object property. I want to include a drop down list of my object (read from database) across my webpage.

This is my object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string browser { get; set; }    
    public string protocol { get; set; }    
    public string family { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
    ViewBag.Files = new SelectList(list, "Id", "protocol");
    return View();
}
```

I also try:

```
List<MyObject> list = db.Captures.Where(x => x.family == "Web")
         .DistinctBy(y => y.protocol)
         .ToList();
```

Index.cshtml

```
  @Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files), "Select webmail site", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })
```

What i want to see in my DropDownList is my protocol property.
All the above not help and all i can see all the time is `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller to:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Files = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
    return View();
}
```

and your `Index.cshtml`

```
@Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(list, "Id", "protocol"), "Select webmail site", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })
```

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriatel and it marked you line with red color

Comment: I've changed my answer to send a `IEnumerable<MyObject>` to the View and create the `SelectList` inside of it

Comment: Why the name list does not exist in the correct context ? should i replace it in other thing ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: BTW, can i remove the duplication's from my DropDownList ?

Comment: What `Id` do you want to use? If you have 3 protocols with different ids maybe you want something more than `.DistinctBy(y => y.protocol)`

Comment: i want to return all my objects list and show on my DropDownList only the property protocol but in case there is more than 1 object with the same protocol -> show this protocol only once